# DAX: How to override one component of an evaluation context

Tags: powershell, filter, dax

I'm creating a line and stacked column chart and having a problem with the measure that should be plotted on the line.
The x-axis is time (one entry for each month). I have two slicers, and the bars on the chart are correct.

We want the line to be a constant value that represents the budget as it was planned in January. So I want to continue using the slicer values in the filter but want to override the time context. I tried:

```
    Annual Budget = CALCULATE (
                        'Measures'[Annual OP],
                         KEEPFILTERS(Month('Date'[Date] = 1))
                    )
```

What I'm trying to do here is keep the slicer filters but then force date filter to always use month 1. What I'm seeing is that Annual Budget still changes monthly and equals the Annual OP value for each month.

Answer (score 1):

Since there was no sample data we can create a small model that I hope might help.

Sales table

| Date | Amount | Product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 10 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 20 | 2 |
| 2020-02-05 | 15 | 1 |
| 2020-02-06 | 25 | 2 |
| 2020-03-04 | 50 | 1 |

A Calendar table with the MonthNumber and WeekDayNumber, just to test slicers

```
Calendar = 
ADDCOLUMNS( 
    CALENDAR( "2020-01-01", "2020-03-31"), 
    "Month Number", MONTH( [Date] ),
    "WeekDayNumber", WEEKDAY( [Date] ) 
)
```

and then a relationship on the Date column creates the model

[image: data model]

Then the [Sales Amount] measure

```
Sales Amount = SUM( Sales[Amount] )
```

Now we can write a measure to compute the Sales Amount for the first Calendar[MonthNumber] in the current selection made with the slicer, to do so we use [ALLSELECTED](https://dax.guide/allselected/)

```
First Month Sales Amount = 
VAR FirstMonth = CALCULATE( MIN ( Calendar[Month Number] ), ALLSELECTED( 'Calendar' ) )
RETURN
CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    'Calendar'[Month Number] = FirstMonth
)
```

If the month is always january instead of the first one of the slicer selection, then we  can write a different measure

```
January Sales Amount = 
CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    'Calendar'[Month Number] = 1 
)
```

And now we can create a Line and Stacked Column Chart, with First or January Month Sales Amount measure for the line, the Sales Amount for the columns, with a slicer on Sales[Product], a slicer on Calendar[Month] and a slicer on Calendar[WeekdayNumber].

Since we want to use the line a a reference for the column, we want to use the same Y axis and therefore we set the property "show secondary" of the Y axis to off

[image: show secondary off]

now the chart behaves like expected, changing accordingly to the slicers selection

[image: chart 1]

[image: chart 2]

Comment: I saved the sample pbix on github, here is the link for the direct download https://github.com/SergioMurru/shared/raw/main/chuckbo%20DAX%20How%20to%20override%20one%20component%20of%20an%20evaluation%20context/chuckbo%20DAX%20How%20to%20override%20one%20component%20of%20an%20evaluation%20context.pbix